# Riemann-Hilbert Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

I am wondering several things about the [Riemann-Hilbert Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hilbert_problem) :

- What is the significance of the Riemann-Hilbert Problem?
- If solved, how pivotal to mathematics will its effect be?
- What background is needed to fully understand the problem?

Comment: The applications listed in section 3 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Riemann-Hilbert+problem) show what the significance is. How pivotal will its effects be? Very pivotal. Background: Complex analysis, algebraic geometry etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would like a simple motivating example of the Riemann-Hilbert problem if possible.